# Source of Cases without RecordType

Tags: record-type, web-to-case

We have setup Email-to-Case and Web-to-Case in our organization. We added 'RECTYPEA' RecordType in our multiple Email-to-Case.

But, while running Report, we're finding Cases being created without RecordType. Now, Firstly I thought it would be because of Cases getting created by Web-to-Case but when I tried creating a case using Web-to-Case, it goes directly to 'RECTYPEA' even if I haven't mentioned the recordtype in the HTML generated by Web-to-Case.

These cases have the CreatedBy 'System'. Now, After some R&D, if I found out that, 'RECTYPEA'is default RecrodType for my Administrator profile. If I change the default record type for my Administrator profile to 'RECTYPEB', my Web-to-Case goes to 'RECTYPEB'.

Now, I have no idea how the Cases without RecordType are being created. Am I missing some obvious detail in this?

Comment: can you check if any other trigger or workflows or processes are getting involved in post creation

Comment: are any profiles configured where their default recordtype is Master?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, the cases that are without RecordType have the same profile and that profile has default case recordtype set as 'Master'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: go to those profiles and change the default recordtype to an explicitly enumerated one